# Trying to find the minimum value of a list in python 3 without using the min function

Tags: python-3.x

So far I have this

```
import random
numbers = []
for i in range(10):
    numbers.append(random.randint(-100,100))
current_Min = 0
def minimum(x):
    current_Min= numbers[0]
    for i in numbers:
        if i < current_Min:
            current_Min = i
    return current_Min
minimum(numbers)
print(numbers)
print(current_Min)
```

but it's not returning the minimum like I would like it too. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `def` you should use the parameter x instead of numbers.

`def minimum(x):
    current_Min= x[0]
    for i in x:
        if i < current_Min:
            current_Min = i
    return current_Min`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use global variables here. The value of "current_Min" is different inside the function (due to Python's rules this is a local value) and outside the function (it is a global variable). Instead use the parameters, and the return value.

```
import random

def minimum(x):
    current_Min= x[0]
    for i in x:
        if i < current_Min:
            current_Min = i
    return current_Min

numbers = []
for i in range(10):
    numbers.append(random.randint(-100,100))

current_Min = minimum(numbers)
```